# How to make X work in old laptop? (Vector Linux)

Tags: linux, xorg

I found out about Vector Linux not too long ago and decided to give it a try to bring an old Acer Aspire laptop back to life. Before doing so, I thought it would be good to try VL on a virtual machine with the same characteristics of the laptop. I was quickly impressed so the next step was to install the OS on the laptop.

The installation went smoothly, as is the GRUB splash screen, but when I rebooted in order to start using VL, X started acting up. The screen went gray, no mouse pointer, and when I pressed Ctrl + Alt + Del, I could see at the top a miniature area that showed what was going on (the usual shutdown process).

I managed to get into a terminal and saved the X log (**var/log/Xorg.0.log**) to a file:

```
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   812.470] (EE) systemd-logind: failed to get session: The name org.freedesktop.login1 was not provided by any .service files
[   812.625] (EE) Failed to load /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so: libepoxy.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[   812.625] (EE) Failed to load module "glamoregl" (loader failed, 7)
[   813.015] (EE) Failed to load module "modesetting" (module does not exist, 0)
[   813.016] (EE) Failed to load module "fbdev" (module does not exist, 0)
[   815.744] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
[   815.816] (EE) AIGLX error: dlopen of /usr/lib/xorg/modules/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (libelf.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
[   815.816] (EE) GLX: could not load software renderer
[   828.353] (EE) 
[   828.353] (EE) Backtrace:
[   828.573] (EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x4f) [0x81f22cf]
[   828.573] (EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (0x8048000+0x1ae1c6) [0x81f61c6]
[   828.573] (EE) 2: /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xb76e7000+0xf950) [0xb76f6950]
[   828.573] (EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/sis_drv.so (0xb6d55000+0x4f072) [0xb6da4072]
[   828.573] (EE) 4: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/sis_drv.so (0xb6d55000+0x3aad9) [0xb6d8fad9]
[   828.573] (EE) 5: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/sis_drv.so (0xb6d55000+0x29095) [0xb6d7e095]
[   828.573] (EE) 6: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libexa.so (0xb6d18000+0x5572) [0xb6d1d572]
[   828.573] (EE) 7: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libexa.so (0xb6d18000+0x5abf) [0xb6d1dabf]
[   828.573] (EE) 8: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libexa.so (0xb6d18000+0x5c97) [0xb6d1dc97]
[   828.573] (EE) 9: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libexa.so (0xb6d18000+0x64ba) [0xb6d1e4ba]
[   828.573] (EE) 10: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libexa.so (0xb6d18000+0x41af) [0xb6d1c1af]
[   828.573] (EE) 11: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libexa.so (0xb6d18000+0xa44d) [0xb6d2244d]
[   828.573] (EE) 12: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libexa.so (0xb6d18000+0xaf9b) [0xb6d22f9b]
[   828.573] (EE) 13: /usr/bin/X (0x8048000+0x12811b) [0x817011b]
[   828.573] (EE) 14: /usr/bin/X (0x8048000+0x302a3) [0x80782a3]
[   828.574] (EE) 15: /usr/bin/X (0x8048000+0x33ffd) [0x807bffd]
[   828.574] (EE) 16: /usr/bin/X (0x8048000+0x38135) [0x8080135]
[   828.574] (EE) 17: /usr/bin/X (0x8048000+0x210ee) [0x80690ee]
[   828.574] (EE) 18: /lib/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0xb73b4df5]
[   828.574] (EE) 19: /usr/bin/X (0x8048000+0x21115) [0x8069115]
[   828.574] (EE) 
[   828.574] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x0
[   828.574] (EE) 
[   828.574] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[   828.574] (EE) 
[   828.574] (EE) 
[   828.574] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[   828.574] (EE) 
[   828.881] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

and the output of **lspci | grep -i vga**:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 661/741/760 PCI/AGP or 662/761Gx PCIE VGA Display Adapter
```

Any ideas about what I can do to make this work? Any ideas will be more than welcome.

Comment: Fun with graphic drivers. I'd recommend you to google for `Sis x11`, `761Gx crash` etc. , there are quite a few bug reports and forum entries from a few years back. Since VL is based on Slackware, googling `Slackware SiS` might be helpful. Best of luck with debugging this.

Answer (score 1):

I happen to own an old laptop with this same crappy video card and have managed to make it work (surprise!) with Vector Linux 64bit version 7.1.

What you have to do is to search the Linux Questions foruns, where a user has provided an unofficial (slackbuild) package for the "Sisimedia" driver, incorporating several different patches collected from the web and the modified sources that Arch Linux ships.

Using that slackbuild you can install the driver and it will work, though not well enough for a modern desktop. I strongly encourage you to use it with something very light, like IceWM (which Vector provides in a slightly customized version that is quite useable, though bare).

But I will spare you some of the pain providing the link:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/slackware-and-sis-771-671-drivers-slackbuild-4175511356/

I don't know how Linux-savvy you are, but slackbuild scripts are fairly easy to use. Just read the docs. The author of the slackbuild really deserves a beer.